# Create date range validator that accepts parameter "Today"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes

I have created date range attribute that looks like this:

```
[DateRange(Min = "Today")]
```

Inside this attribute I get min date like this:

```
...
var minDate = DateTime.Now;
...
```

**EDIT:** Here is more code:

```
private DateTime _minDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-100);
private DateTime _maxDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

// String representation of the Min Date (yyyy/MM/dd)
public string Min
{
    get { return FormatDate(_minDate, DateTime.Today.AddYears(-100)); }
    set { _minDate = value == "Today" ? DateTime.Today : ParseDate(value, DateTime.Today.AddYears(-100)); }
}
// String representation of the Max Date (yyyy/MM/dd)
public string Max
{
    get { return FormatDate(_maxDate, DateTime.MaxValue); }
    set { _maxDate = value == "Today" ? DateTime.Today : ParseDate(value, DateTime.MaxValue); }
}
```

Because of the nature of attributes, minDate is set only once when compiled. Can you show me alternative way of implementing this functionality?

Comment: Alternative, as in what way?

Answer (score 0):

Use [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx).

Come to think of it, what if you mark the contents (minDate) as [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx)?  Please do and report back whether it works or not.  If it works I have some updates to do myself.